# How to find a previous item and add a class to it using php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a class called 'current-menu', and I want to find its previous sibling and add a class called 'previous-menu', how can I achieve it with php only?

I can do this with jquery,

```
$("#menu-header .current-menu").parent().prev().find('a').addClass('current-previous');
```

but it is slow to add the previous class on the client side so I am thinking using the server side to archive it. Is it possible?

this is my html and php code that generate, 'first-menu', 'current-menu' and the 'last-menu',

```
<?php
foreach($items as $index => $item):
?>

<li><a href="#"<?php 
if ($parent->pg_url == $item['pg_url']) echo ' class="current-menu"';
elseif($index == ($total_items - 1)) echo ' class="last-menu"'; 
elseif($index == '0') echo ' class="first-menu"';
?>><?php echo $item['mnu_name'];?></a></li>

<?php endforeach;?>
```

so it generate something like this,

```
<!--menu-->
<ul id="menu-header">
<li><a href="#" class="first-menu">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Venues</a></li>
<li><a href="#">How to visit</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="current-menu">Active Space</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="last-menu">Resources</a></li>
</ul>
<!--menu-->
```

So I want to add **'previous-menu'** to this node,

```
<li><a href="#">How to visit</a></li>
```

to become this,

```
<li><a href="#" class="previous-menu">How to visit</a></li>
```

below is the data I get from the database,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [mnu_id] => 1
            [mnu_name] => Home
            [mnu_url] => 
            [mnu_additional] => 
            [mnu_order] => 1
            [pg_url] => home
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [mnu_id] => 5
            [mnu_name] => About
            [mnu_url] => 
            [mnu_additional] => 
            [mnu_order] => 2
            [pg_url] => about
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [mnu_id] => 6
            [mnu_name] => Venues
            [mnu_url] => 
            [mnu_additional] => 
            [mnu_order] => 3
            [pg_url] => venues
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [mnu_id] => 3
            [mnu_name] => How to visit
            [mnu_url] => 
            [mnu_additional] => 
            [mnu_order] => 4
            [pg_url] => how to visit
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [mnu_id] => 2
            [mnu_name] => Project Archive
            [mnu_url] => 
            [mnu_additional] => 
            [mnu_order] => 5
            [pg_url] => projects
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [mnu_id] => 8
            [mnu_name] => Active Space
            [mnu_url] => 
            [mnu_additional] => 
            [mnu_order] => 6
            [pg_url] => active space
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [mnu_id] => 4
            [mnu_name] => Contact
            [mnu_url] => 
            [mnu_additional] => 
            [mnu_order] => 7
            [pg_url] => contact
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [mnu_id] => 7
            [mnu_name] => News
            [mnu_url] => 
            [mnu_additional] => 
            [mnu_order] => 8
            [pg_url] => 
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [mnu_id] => 9
            [mnu_name] => Resources
            [mnu_url] => 
            [mnu_additional] => 
            [mnu_order] => 9
            [pg_url] => resources
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution. I assume that some items may have 2 classes.

```
<?php
$items[0]['class'] = "first_menu ";
$items[$total_items - 1]['class'] = "last-menu ";

foreach ($items as $index => &$item) {
    if (!$item['class']) {
        $item['class'] = '';
    }
    if ($parent->pg_url == $item['pg_url']) {
        $item['class'] .= "current-menu ";
        if ($index > 0) {
            $items[$index - 1]['class'] .= "previous-menu ";
        }
    }
}

foreach($items as $index => $item):
?>

<li><a href="#"<?php 
if ($item['class']) echo ' class="' . trim($item['class']) . '"';
?>><?php echo $item['mnu_name'];?></a></li>

<?php endforeach;?>
```